# Multiple screens

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, hardware

Apple community!

In a couple of months, I will be setting up a booth at my high school. My booth will probably have some sort of table or desk for my MacBook (see below for specs) and more relevantly, some type of tv or screen. I will need to be able to loop a video either from a file or YouTube (it doesn't matter as I will have it as both) on the screen, which I will probably connect to through my *Thunderbolt* port, which I can adapt to *HDMI*.

Here's the tricky part: I will need to be able to show people various things on my MacBook's screen at the same time as the video is looping. I am well versed in screensharing, but that will (obviously) not work in this case.

[Specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html):

> The Apple MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.0 13-Inch (Unibody - Late 2008/Aluminum) features a 45 nm "Penryn" 2.0 GHz Intel "Core 2 Duo" processor (P7350), with two independent processor "cores" on a single silicon chip, a 3 MB shared "on chip" level 2 cache, a 1066 MHz frontside bus, 2 GB of 1066 MHz DDR3 SDRAM (PC3-8500) installed in pairs (two 1 GB modules), a 160 GB Serial ATA (5400 RPM) hard drive, an 8X DL "SuperDrive", a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M "graphics processor with 256 MB of DDR3 SDRAM shared with main memory", integrated iSight, and an LED-backlit 13.3" widescreen TFT active-matrix "glossy" display (1280x800 native resolution).
>
> Connectivity includes AirPort Extreme (802.11a/b/g/n), Bluetooth 2.1+EDR, Gigabit Ethernet, two USB 2.0 ports, optical digital/analog audio in/out, and a new "Mini DisplayPort" that supports an external display at 2560x1600. It does not include a Firewire "400" port.

I will say that I've updated to Yosemite, a 500 gb solid state memory, and 16 gb of ram.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to do this is to extend (not mirror) your desktop.**

Have your video playing on the external monitor while your MBP screen will be free to show other items.

1. Make sure each display is properly connected and powered on.
2. From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.
3. From the View menu, choose Displays.
4. Click the Arrangement tab.
5. Disable (uncheck) "Mirror Displays".

[image]